# Change from color to text in column T

Tags: excel, vba

I have a small question.
I would like to change the row  -  `Then Worksheets("List_Shipped").Cells(i, 1).**EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 102, 102)` -  to be a comment in the cell instead of color the entirerow .

The SO-60542 are in cell C3 and I would like cell L3 to say PAY or NOT PAY if C3 would be SO-60547

Example of my vba code now.

```
If Worksheets("List_Shipped").Cells(i, 3).Value = "SO-60542" Then
    Worksheets("List_Shipped").Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 102, 102) 
ElseIf Worksheets("List_Shipped").Cells(i, 3).Value = "SO-60606" Then
     Worksheets("List_Shipped").Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 102, 102)
```

Comment: I would think the macro recorder would be very helpful here.

Comment: Also, you can just say `rows(i).`  and formula based conditional formatting may help too.  Look at `.AddComment`

Comment: `Then Worksheets("List_Shipped").Cells(i, 12).value = "PAY"`? Side note: code to change the colour of cells under certain conditions can often be replaced by conditional formatting., similarly `=IF(C1 = "SO-60542", "PAY", "NOT PAY")` could also be used

Comment: Thanks all of you, 
Then Worksheets("List_Shipped").Cells(i, 12).value = "PAY" 
this worked perfect for what I wanted.